# Curious why one proposed edit was accepted and another was not

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Looking for answers to bound and unbound method errors in Python3 I found this post:

[What is the difference between a function, an unbound method and a bound method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949808/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-an-unbound-method-and-a-bound-method/11950331)

Reading the example, I couldn't see the difference in the code (as viewed in my monitor):

```
In [1]: class C(object):  # class named 'C'
   ...:     def f1(self): pass
   ...:
In [2]: c = C()  # an instance
```

Testing the code in a notebook, I realized the variables 'c' and 'C' were upper and lower case. So I edited to use a more readable character, and proposed the change:

```
In [1]: class A(object):  # class named 'A'
   ...:     def f1(self): pass
   ...:
In [2]: a = A()  # an instance
```

I also had to edit two of the answers because each used the same example. I edited these also.

My question, *Why was one answer's proposed change [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16946199) and the other [rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16946182)?* It's just the letter 'c' and 'C', so there should be no rational/logical reason against it.

NOTE, I freely admit I made a mistake editing the very first instance, and incorrectly made an uppercase 'C' into a lowercase 'a'. That said, I do recall when I resigned myself to edit the answers as well, I knew I needed a method to ensure my edits were correct. I figured out if I type a lower case 'c' next to each original instance I could test the character height by visual observation. I'm certain I didn't make the mistake again.

Comment: Because different people reviewed the changes and they had different opinions. There isn't some review board that edits go before to ensure exact consistency.

Comment: Ok. But that begs the question, should I resubmit my changes? The problem the edit fixed is still present. Without feedback as to why the changes were rejected, I don't know what I'm setting myself up against--lazy moderation (too many noodly 'c' and 'C' to bother)  or a more substantial argument. Makes my correction seem arbitrary preference.

Comment: If that's the question you really want to ask then edit your question to actually ask that.

Comment: @xtian I'm actually surprised they weren't both rejected. Changes to codeblocks are hit'n'miss at the best of times - let alone when it's a single letter change. Also `c` and `C` are fairly common for class definitions and instances - I'm not convinced that using `a` or `A` is actually an improvement regardless of how unfortunate it is for you that `c` and `C` are difficult to read. In short - I'm not convinced it's an improvement and you got really, really lucky you had one accepted -- I wouldn't suggest trying to re-submit edits (or make new ones) of a similar nature.

Comment: the reason is no improvements whatsover. Why you're changing the variable names from c to A

Comment: @JonClements that question has a problem now, the question has also been changed. (see [revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/11949808/6)), the class name used in answers naturally was from the question and it's all very confusing now, I don't know python so I'm touching it, but I think it should be restored.

Comment: @xtian you should never change naming as suggested edits specially if you  risk to invalidate or make answers confusing, people reading question will not understand now why in question it is A and then in accepted answer it's C.

Comment: @PetterFriberg what the you are talking about? It's the same question with the same explanation. There's nothing confusing about it, just a little inconsistency which could be very well the answerer preference in naming stuff.

Comment: @Braiam the question and the two answers initial had C, now after the OP has edited some we have the question with A, accepted answer with C and another answer with A, baah it looks confusing to me but I will let the python peps figure out this (note OP edited the question as well to introduce A). However, I just can't see how we can benefit from changing some A to C in some posts, if so let's change one to B

Comment: @PetterFriberg and yet, I've been able to read it just fine.

Comment: @PetterFriberg Yes. Aa is arbitrary and is the initial reading issue is equally resolved by Bb, or Mm, etc.

Comment: @JonClements The issue isn't if C is common. The issue is how they appear to viewers on *their* screen. The reason for the edit was because I couldn't read these characters as distinct, and only when I copied the example and ran the code was the question clear. We read SE on tablets, and smartphones where rendered characters are _even smaller_. To rely on the end user's browser font choice to have a better 'C' x-height to capital ratio fails to understand the diversity of our medium. I'm sorry John, but I disagree with your comment, and I'm surprised anyone is ignorant of these facts.

Comment: @PetterFriberg Your point about confusion is the reason for my post. I did the work to make the edit to *all* of the examples. But only two (the OP and one answer) were approved. I want to do the work to fix the third, but I'm not sure why the rejection, so I don't know if I will recreated the same situation.

Comment: @xtian I apologise for being ignorant of the fact that your device is incapable of displaying a lowercase and uppercase letter such you have difficulty disambiguating them - although in all my years here, having read the site on various devices, and all the questions I've seen - you're the only user (of which there's millions) to have this issue and try to justify it as a reason for a minor edit. I've tried the polite way of saying it with additional information as to why. I'll go for the blunt way. These edits are not acceptable - do not make them.

Comment: @JonClements Its not the device, its the font _choice_. (Which happens to be the default with my Archlinux install)

Comment: @xtian then fix the issue at the source. **Do not  suggest edits** on the site to do so.

Comment: I sort of expected a moderator might post the given reason for the rejection, which is what I typically find here in Meta. Nevertheless, thank you all for the lively arguments.

Comment: @xtian Are you sure you're not confusing that with rejected **flags** being explained? Suggested edits are reviewed by any volunteer with the necessary site privileges, there is little a moderator can explain about what random users of the site choose to do.

Comment: @Gimby There's comments on all edits on the user side. What you're describing is a 'Approve/Reject' switch. Is that the case with edits on the mod side?